# DROP DEFAULT on psql restore fails because column not existing anymore

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pg-dump, default-value, pg-restore

A dump creates a command to remove default values like:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS test.simulation ALTER COLUMN gid DROP DEFAULT;
```

When on restore the column with the default value do not exist anymore, the restore gets an error:

```
ERROR: column "gid" of relation "simulation" does not exist
```

I solved my problem by deleting the table first manually, but I wonder if there would be a better sollution.

## The scenario looks like this

The table "test.simulation" before creating the dump:

```
thebase=# \d+ test.simulation
                                                              Table "test.simulation"
   Column   |              Type              |                              Modifiers                              | Storage | Stats target | Description
------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 gid        | integer                        | not null default nextval('test.simulation_gid_seq'::regclass)       | plain   |              |
 objectid   | numeric                        |                                                                     | main    |              |
```

I make a dump of the table like this:

```
pg_dump --clean --if-exists -hlocalhost -p5432 -dthebase -Upostgres -ttest.simulation -Fplain -f/var/lib/postgresql/backup.sql"
```

Then I remove the column "gid" from the table "test.simulation". And because I shouldn't have done it I recreate it:

```
psql -hlocalhost -p5432 -dthebase -Upostgres --single-transaction -v 'ON_ERROR_STOP=1' -f/var/lib/postgresql/backup.sql"
```

... and the mentioned ERROR occurs. Because it checks if the table exists, but it does not have something like a `DROP DEFAULT IF EXISTS` option.

Comment: I think you shouldn't restore on top of an existing DB to start with.

Comment: Fair enough. But so why the other commands have the IF EXISTS there? That's why I thought it's possibly supported to recreate a table, without deleting it manually first. If I should never restore on an existing DB, I wonder, why it's supported to restore single table at all?

Comment: You can do it in another schema, or by renaming the table (either in the dump or the DB)

Comment: Yes, thanks. Or by deleting it as well. Still in a dump are commands to drop defaults, delete table etc. that would all not be needed, if one would restore only where the table does not exist yet...

Comment: Well, you explicitly asked `pg_dump` to do that when adding teh `--clean` option to the command line...

Comment: Yes. That's why I expected that it will be deleted. If we would only restore on empty space, this option would not be needed. Anyway. I asked if there is a better solution to make it work with the defaults besides the manual deleting/renaming etc. and you responded that there is not. So my question is actually replied. Thanks a lot.